# Product of Bessel function of different order

Tags: bessel-functions

I need to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}J_0^2(\theta)$, where $J_0(\theta)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and of
zeroth order. Actually I need the roots of $J_0^2(\theta)=0$ and hence the derivative is required. Can anyone be of help?

Comment: the derivative is simply $-2 J_0(x)J_1(x)$

Comment: That I know, but what I'm unaware of is that if there exist any closed form expression of the roots of $J_0^2(\theta)$.

Comment: There are no closed form expressions. Only very good approximations...

Comment: That'll also serve the purpose... please do give some suitable references.

Comment: You can google for 'roots of bessel functions' to find many resources.  Also, there is a nice calculator here: http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573472